# R equivalent of bash's set -x; echo all commands being executed?

Tags: r

In bash, if you enable `set -x`, the script will echo the evaluated form of all commands to the stderr logs. In tcsh, this same is accomplished with `set echo`. Is there something similar for R? It would help debugging if I had more verbose output of what the script commands look like as they are being run, without having to manually `print` or `cat` every single one.

Answer (score 15):

This answer assumes command-line.

The script is:

```
1 + 1

3 + 3

100 + 100
```

This it running:

```
$ Rscript -e 'source("/tmp/run.R", echo=TRUE)'
## 
## > 1 + 1
## [1] 2
## 
## > 3 + 3
## [1] 6
## 
## > 100 + 100
## [1] 200
```

It shld be trivial to make a wrapper script for that. `littler` might even have an option like this.

Comment: Great! Note that in Windows, you need to use the quotation marks the other way around: Rscript -e "source('/tmp/run.R', echo=TRUE)"; if it is all the same for Linux, perhaps you could change your answer to use this. Also, by using verbose=TRUE instead, you get even more information. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately it does not print the line being executed for statements within for-loops, not to mention function calls...

Comment: You can also create a custom source function that prints lines from any construct you are interested in, for example, based on http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html

Comment: I wrote a bash function to make it easier to run:

`rsc(){Rscript -e 'source(file("stdin"),echo=TRUE,spaced=TRUE)'< ${1}
}`

Comment: Another way to use this option is typing `options(echo=T)` at the beginning of the script